# MySQL REGEXP NOT operator for groups

Tags: mysql, regex

In this dummy example, I am trying to match every animal who is not either a `cat` or a `dog`: `(cat|dog)`. I therefore need a `NOT` operator to negate my `(cat|dog)` group. Does MySQL provide such a thing ?

```
SELECT 'I am a cat' REGEXP '^I am a [NOT](cat|dog)$'; -> 0
SELECT 'I am a dog' REGEXP '^I am a [NOT](cat|dog)$'; -> 0
SELECT 'I am a horse' REGEXP '^I am a [NOT](cat|dog)$'; -> 1
SELECT 'I am not a dog' REGEXP '^I am a [NOT](cat|dog)$'; -> 1
SELECT 'I am a catwoman' REGEXP '^I am a [NOT](cat|dog)$'; -> 1
```

I have read the [MySQL REGEXP documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) several times without success.

Comment: Will you always get input in the form of 'not a dog' or 'not a cat' for your last case?

Comment: Should it match "he is a horse"?  "he is a cat"?  "I am a wildcat"?  In other words, you have under-specified the problem, so we cannot accurately help you.  Please rephrase it and provide more examples.

Comment: You are right, I tried to simplify my problem too much. I'll rewrite my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
REGEXP 'I am (a [^(cat|dog)])|(not a (cat|dog))';
```

The caret at the start will check that the word is NOT cat or dog. Failing that, it will check if the statement says 'not a cat' or 'not a dog'. This solution assumes that to be the only other way of expressing that the animal is not a cat or dog, apart from the actual name.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/38858)

Comment: `[^(cat|dog)]` is exactly what I was looking for, thanks !